# What are some surprising theories that contain Robinson arithmetic?

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory

I'm looking for theories that enable defining natural numbers and proving Robinson arithmetic (like ZF and Peano) but in a nontrivial or even a surprising way.

Comment: if I remember correctly, I think (with parameters) $(\mathbb{F}_p(t),\cdot,+)$ defines the set $\{t^n:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ and also the natural induced structure of arithmetic on it. I will try to find the reference later